# Convert saved png files into a movie/gif

Tags: python, video, directory, png, gif

I am very new to python. I have a folder which contains many .png files (which are scatter plots I previously made in python). I want to write a script that turns these files into a movie.

My files are named 0.png 1.png 2.png .... 49.png

I tried the following

```
    frames = []
    for i in range(0,M):
        frames.append(f'{i}.png')
 
    
    gif.save(frames, "mymovie.gif",duration=15, unit="s",between="startend")
```

Where this gif function saves the list of frames as a movie. But I have no idea what to be calling in the frames.append(), at the moment I just get a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it "Pillow" library.

```
from PIL import Image

sample_image = Image.open("sample_image.png")
sample_image.save('.gif')
```

You can look at the other features of Pillow;
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `imageio.v3`, see example from [Documentation](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#) (code includes frame creation):

```
import imageio.v3 as iio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n = 100
gif_path = "test.gif"

plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4))
for x in range(n):
    plt.scatter(x / n, x / n)
    plt.xlim(0, 1)
    plt.ylim(0, 1)
    plt.savefig(f"{x}.jpg")

#Generating the gif with all the frames:
frames = np.stack([iio.imread(f"{x}.jpg") for x in range(n)], axis=0)

iio.imwrite(gif_path, frames)
```

[image]

Comment: why n=100 twice?

Comment: Indeed, not useful. I removed it.